# Как можно вывести битрейт для аудио в формате mp3?

Tags: javascript, html5, mp3

Как, используя тег `<audio>`, вывести битрейт с помощью js?

Comment: Может они с сервера получают данные по битрейту, вместе с аудио потоком.

Comment: если вы видели реализацию на «некоторых сайтах», попробуйте разобрать их реализацию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не претендую на абсолютную истину, но, из школьной программы математики можно вспомнить задачи про скорость, время и расстояние (S = V * t). В случае с mp3 расстояние -- размер файла, время -- очевидно время звучание, а битрейт -- ни что иное, как скорость потока. Поэтому, можно сделать следующее:

- узнать путь к источнику из свойства audio.src;
- запросить источник методом HEAD, кроме всего прочего получим размер файла в байтах (заголовок Content-Length), пусть это будет S;
- узнать время звучания в секундах из свойства audio.duration, пусть это будет t;
- По формуле V = S / t получим примерную скорость потока в байтах в секунду (у нас есть еще заголовок файла и теги, они тоже занимают место);
- Разделив полученную величину на 128 (V = V / 1024 * 8) получим скорость потока в килобитах в секунду.

Comment: Это не сработает, если к mp3-файлу прикреплена большая обложка альбома

Comment: Согласен, поэтому и написал, что расчеты примерны.

Comment: Спасибо но уже реализовал, по такой же схеме. Но как и предполагалось что то точно показывает, а где-то есть обложка которая добавляет вес  и лишний битрейт. По сути это просто цифры....

Answer (score 2):

mp3 файлы состоят из мелких отрезков, т.н. фреймов (кадров), и каждый может иметь свой битрейт и частоту дискретизации.

В начале фрейма идёт [заголовок](http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html) из 4 байтов:

```
AAAAAAAA AAABBCCD EEEEFFGH IIJJKLMM
```

Битрейт записан битами E – первые 4 бита 3-го байта. См. по ссылке выше возможные значения.

Читать бинарные данные в JS можно [несколькими способами](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data).

Остаётся прочитать все фреймы и усреднить битрейт? =)

Ещё вариант – на стороне сервера вытащить все возможные метаданные о файле, и держать их, скажем, в .json файле с таким же именем, как mp3.

Вытащить можно, например, утилитой [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html).